# Definition of element

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

In Charles C. Pinter's A Book of Set Theory, the definition of element is given. Here is the definition given:

Let $x$ be a class. If $x$ is an element of some class $A$ then $x$ is called an element.

I will try to symbolize the definition, with respect to the primitive notions of $\in$ and class. I will use the conventions of lower-case and upper-case letters independent of the standard conventions, but still used to guide the reader.

$$\forall x(Element(x)\Leftrightarrow(Class(x)\wedge \exists X(Class(X)\wedge x \in X))) $$

My secondary symbolization follows more closely to what is written in English.

$$\forall x(Class(x)\Rightarrow (Element(x)\Leftrightarrow \exists X(Class(X)\wedge x\in X)))$$

If any of these are the correct interpretation of the definition, which one is it? If none of these are correct, could you offer a symbolic interpretation? I am leaning towards the first translation since an iff statement to me encompasses all the information as a definition would.

The motivation for this question was simply my curiosity, as I could not justify to myself which one was a better symbolism, and so I felt uneasy with the natural language expression.

Comment: Yes, the second one formalizes the "conditional definition" above, i.e.the def of "element of" that applies to *classes*. Having said that, I'm not sure about the usefulness of such a definition: "if $x$ is an *element* of a class, then it is an element" ??

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, to me it would be useful for first-order logic derivations. Also, in some early point in the book, the author goes on about providing the reasons why we need to give the definition, which is to prevent the logical paradoxes.